# Can iMacros click a button and not wait for a response?

Tags: javascript, scripting, automation, imacros

I am using iMacros v6.90 on Windows 7 in the iMacros Browser.  I have a script that stopped working due to some website change that I do not understand.  The issue is the following line:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=NAME:cmdLogin
```

I have discovered that if I manually goto the login page, all works fine, but for some reason, clicking this `Login` button does not cause the page to reload and iMacros hangs waiting for a response that never comes.

Note that the button shows at the lower bottom left this text when the mouse hovers over the `Login` button:

```
javascript: void(0):
```

I'd like after clicking the above link to not wait for a response and just proceed with:

```
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=https://www.website.com/Welcome.aspx
```

I tried using iMacros' Stealth Mode to look like Internet Explorer, but I get the same issue.

Is there a way to click the button but tell iMacros to not stop and wait for a response?

Comment: This seams confusing. Can you change the page loading time?
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 5

Comment: @macroscripts No, there is some kind of bug, clicking the login button does nothing no matter how long you wait.  I discovered, that after clicking the button, manually going to the normal login URL, shows you are logged in.

Comment: Try recording the click to Login button with EVENT command.

Comment: @macroscripts I tried: `EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=""#cmdLogin"" BUTTON=0` but it appears v6.90 does not support the EVENT command.

Comment: Move on to newer version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical occurrence when working with facebook or other heavy sites that load lots of JS code in the background. Some sites like facebook stop loading certain JS elements behind buttons after you abuse them to much as a sort of protection and some just crash. The impact for users is minor since we just refresh or press other stuff and forget one button didn't work once but macros completely mess up.

To overcome this I add random "refresh" between actions or manually go to www.domain.com (the domain home page) and back to where I wanted to help avoid these bugs.

In some cases there is a real bug with the button JS.